# Adjust specific text lables in ggplot to avoid overlap

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, label

Given a dummy data set:

```
V1<-c(1,10,30,22,22,20)
V2<-c(4,17,4,33,33.2,15)
V3<-c(20,20,15,34,33,30)
V4<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
DF<-data.frame(V1,V2,V3,V4)
```

If I were to plot a bubble plot like so:

```
symbols(DF$V1,DF$V2,circles=V3,inches=0.35,fg="darkblue",bg="red")
text(DF$V1,DF$V2,V4,cex=0.5)
```

I get some overlap with the 4th and 5th label text. Using the below code, I can remove this overlap by adjusting specific points

```
text(DF$V1,DF$V2+c( 0, 0, 0, 1, -1,0 ),V4,cex=0.5)
```

Which works fine, but I would like to work in ggplot. If I do a simple ggplot

```
ggplot(DF,aes(x=V1,y=V2,size=V3,label=V4),legend=FALSE)+geom_point(color='darkblue',fill="red", shape=21)+theme_bw()+geom_text(size=5)
```

I get the same overlap, but I don't know how to adjust the individual points to avoid the overlap. I've tried using "thigmophobe.labels", but that adjusts all points. I'd like to just slightly adjust the points that overlap as to make them readable.

Answer (score 5):

If the data value being overlapped is not very important, a quick and dirty solution is to specify:

```
+ geom_text(size = 5, check_overlap = T)
```

So that text overlap previous text will not be plotted.

Answer (score 3):

Add `position=position_jitter()` and play with the `width` and `height` argument.   eg

```
 + geom_text(size=5, position=position_jitter(width=1, height=2) )
```

Comment: I normally like jitter, but in this case I'm trying to keep my points uniformly spaced and in the same orientation from the bubble points, only adjusting the points that overlap

Comment: for precise control, create an additional column in your data, and adjust the points as you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `directlabels` package. It might have what you need. (Specifically the function `direct.label` wrapped around the `ggplot` code.)

Comment: [directlabels](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/directlabels/directlabels.pdf) is the name.